# What is the preferred approach regarding "I'm new to ..."

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users, etiquette

There are many questions opening with I am new to this and that.
It seems very meta and irrelevant. It's not like I'll you will act differently to a noob question according to the faq:

> Etiquette
>
> Civility is required at all times; rudeness [will not be tolerated.](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette)

So the question is should I edit it out? is it constrictive in any way?

I believe it should be treated like `'hi'` and `'thanks'` and same arguments against those apply:
Wastes space on preview, irrelevant,not broad,etc'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would normally remove that and any other irrelevant preamble.

Things that do not add to the question and are only diversions (or attempts at explaining why the community should be tolerant of the question - in particular for off-topic/no-research questions) - these I will remove.

A valid question is a valid question - doesn't matter if the person is new. Keeping such an introduction in the question just takes attention away from the question itself.

Comment: @Ben - Mostly, newbie questions are not in need of tailoring.

Comment: @Ben - Also, you will note that I keep saying _relevant_. If this is a _relevant_ detail, then I will keep it. Normally, it isn't.

Comment: @Ben Well, oftentimes it's obvious from the question itself.  When someone asks "How do I write out text to the console in C#" I really don't need to know that they're new.  I find it's mostly relevant if a new programmer manages to stumble across a particularly complex question (which happens, but is uncommon).

Comment: @Servy I agree with you. Even with 'noob' type of questions you learn from them.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't have any problem with people writing "I'm new to..."; it enables answerers to target the sophistication of their answer to the level of the questioner. It can be important to simplify things when someone is struggling with a concept that they are not used to and there's nothing wrong with being polite to the questioner.

I *do*, however, minify the statement as much as possible. For instance, if they wrote:

> I'm new to xxx and I have no idea how to go about doing this. I've
>   been searching Google... `<blah>` and need to ferschmuzzle the kerbuzzle

I change this to:

> I'm new to xx and need to ferschmuzzle the kerbuzzle.

P.S. I'm sure this is a duplicate but I can't find it.

Comment: I was sure it was asked before but couldn't find anything either.